# how to open a gz file and save the file as txt in python

Tags: python, io, gzip

I have a gz file, how can I unzip the file and save the content to a txt in python?
I imported gzip already

```
file_path = gzip.open(file_name, 'rb')
```

Comment: Have you tried seeing what functions are now available for this object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about opening a second file and writing to it?

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'rb') as f, open('file.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write(f.read())
```

Answer (score 2):

Gzip's open method should open the file in such a way that its contents can be read like a normal file:

```
import gzip

#Define the file's location
file_path = "/path/to/file.gz"

#Open the file and read its contents
with gzip.open(file_path, "rb") as file:
    file_content = file.read()


#Save the new txt file
txt_file_name = "txtFile.txt"

with open(txt_file_name, "w") as file:
    file.write(file_content)
```